# The Caveats of Sub States?

Tags: ngxs

I am a newbie and hacking around with ngxs.

On the docs [There are caveats to Sub States](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/sub-states#caveats).

- This is only intended to work with nested objects, so trying to create stores on nested array objects will not work.
- Sub states can only be used once, reuse implies several restrictions that would eliminate some high value features. If you want to re-use them, just create a new state and inherit from it.

I believe I understand the first point to a small degree but I don't fully grasp what the second point means.

Would someone be able to expand on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it means that a single state class can't be a child of multiple parent classes. the workaround would be to create new states by extending. so

```
@State({
  name: 'foo' // you can't have another state with this name
})
class MyState1 {}

// so if you want to reuse the listeners and such from 'foo' you have to extend
@State({
  name: 'bar'
})
class MyState2 extends MyState1 {}
```